# Defer parsing of JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, caching, iframe

Gtmetrix says there are some JS files coming from youtube which need to be deferred. I removed iframe and deferred it using jQuery and also through classic Javascript code but both methods are not working. Gtmetrix still displays same youtube JS files.

The error in Gtmetrix
[image]
Here is the Javascript code I am currently using

```
<script>
var txt = '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qwertyuiopa?feature=oembed&amp;wmode=opaque" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].innerHTML = txt;
</script>
```

PS: Yes I removed cache and there is no `<iframe>` tag in source code and that JS code is working well as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can try extracting your JS code into a `.js` file and then use `defer` or `async` attributes of the `<script />` HTML element.

```
<script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
```

Those attributes shouldn't be used on `script` tags without a `src`, that's why it is important to extract the code into a separate JS file.

Hope it helps.